# Will Hiding Form Labels Impact Web Accessibility?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, usability, accessibility

I have a shipping form.  Three input fields surround the shipping address.

Below are the labels (and in parenthesis their "for" values)

1) Address/P.O. Box (for="shipAddress1")
2) Address 2 (for="shipAddress2")
3) Use for International Address only(for="shipAddress3")

Our designer has proposed to label them simple as "Street Address or P/O Box", but I still want to present these 3 labels for Web Accessibility (right?).

What should I do with items 1, 2, & 3 above -- should I apply a `text-indent:-1000em;` or something like that. I'm assuming using `display:none` mean screen reader can't see them also, right?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need to show the labels to the user or not?  If not, use `text-indent:-999px` to position them off the page.  `Display:none` will not be picked up by screen readers.

This is a good overview on positioning rather than hiding for accessibility: http://www.nickfitz.co.uk/2007/02/14/why-left-9999px-is-better-for-accessibility-than-display-none/

Still, I'm not entirely sure what you need to show your users.  Your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: I think you've done a good job answering the question (sorry it was a bit confusing). Yes, those 3 labels do not need to be shown to the user. I will go with the negative text indentation. Thank you!

Comment: I was about to ask the same question, merely because HTML5 placeholder text gives visual usability, but you still need labels for screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have three field, only one or two can be filled.
Why not ask the user to choose which filed is filled with an option.

Nicolas